# What is the mean of "the isometries that identify the sides of polygon"?

Tags: algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry

Picture below is from the 167th page of do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry. I don't know the mean of  "the isometries that identify the sides of $P$". My English is poor. I know the process of identifying the sides of polygon to get a surface. For example,  gluing the sides of rectangle by a certain way, we can get the torus.  But I don't know the relation between the gluing and isometry.

First, the isometry will map the internal point of $P$, but the gluing will not affect the internal point of $P$.

Second, the isometry that identify the sides of $P$  is that
$$
I:H^2\rightarrow H^2  ~~~~~~\text{is isometric, and }
~~~~~~I(\partial P)=\partial P 
~~~~\text{?}
$$

> [image]